# Integrating Oauth to to existing User model Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth

I have an existing user sign in and authentication system in place with my rails app.

If adding another provider, such as google, am I able to just add the credentials from the google user to my existing User model, or do I need to create a separate table? What resources can I look to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the awesome railscasts from ryan bates

this episode especially focuses on integrating it within existing application

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Answer (score 1):

railscasts.com has a couple good walk throughs on how to integrate OmniAuth.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity

Hope that helps...